# What to do when a question could belong to multiple stack overflow comunities. e.g SO and Information Security?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Since asking questions is a rigurous thing to do and you could get down votes for very simple mistakes and even possibly get question banned if you accumulate enough.

What happens if I ask a question which could be ambiguous in terms of where the question should be asked ?

For instance, if a question is about programming ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)) and at the same time about security ([Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)).

Is there a way to link both comunities ?

Answer (score 0):

Decide which aspect of your question is more important.  If you're wondering about the security aspects of something, you'd ask it on InfoSec, while if you need help with the implementation details, you'd ask on SO.

(But keep in mind that the programmers on SO are notoriously bad at getting the details of cryptosystems correct.)